# Why aqueous ammonia is added to glucose solution to determine optical rotation?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

In order to determine the specific rotation of glucose, it was mentioned in a practical chemistry book that 10g of dehydrated glucose must be dissolved in 80ml of water, then, adding 0,2ml of aqueous ammonia. After 30 minutes, we have to complete with 100ml of water.

For me, I would prepare only a glucose solution to use in the polarimeter.

So why aqueous ammonia have to be added to the glucose solution ? and why completing with 100ml of water after exactly a half-hour? (What happens during that half-hour?)

Note : This is not a homework. I'm a pharmacy student and this is a part of the lab work I'll have next week.

Comment: Have you already heard of the different isomers of glucose in solution?

Comment: For sure! As far as I know, there are two possible isomers of glucose (Either D-glu or L-glu) in solution. They are alpha-glucose and beta-glucose.

Comment: Approximised you can work with only those four, yes. I'm assuming you know what kind of glucose you will be working with (D or L)? And you have heard of mutarotation?

Comment: For now, I don't really know whether we'll work with D or with L. Yes, mutarotation occurs when alpha-glucopyranose turns into beta-glucopyranose and vice-versa. That's it?

Comment: More or less. You might get relatively pure beta-glucose to work with, or maybe not, so using ammonia and waiting for thirty minutes should equilibrate the solution so the optical activity no longer changes. Ammonia can act as a catalyst for the transformation.

Comment: Now I pretty understood it. Can you provide me the mechanism of action of ammonia ? I mean, how it does catalyze this transformation?

Comment: I think you can manage yourself; $\ce{NH3}$ is nothing more than a base in the catalytic mechanism. ;)